# How do I cause CKEditor to immediately load into the DOM a change made by htmlParser.element.addClass?

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I'm working with an instance of CKEditor (4.5.8) that uses the LITE change tracking plugin (by LoopIndex).

**Goal:** When a user deletes all content in an **li** element, I want to hide the **li** itself (not just the content contained by it*).

*The plugin generates the following markup when you delete all content in an **li**:
      `<li><del>content</del></li>`
    The **del** element is not permitted to wrap **li**, so moving it won't work.

**Work done:** I've added a function in the **dataProcessor**'s **htmlFilter** that finds each **li** element, then calls another function that determines whether the **li** should be hidden. If the **li** should be hidden, I use **htmlParser.element.addClass** to add a "hideListItem" class. I have CSS that sets the **display** of anything having this class to *none*.

The rule works well; when all content in a list item is deleted, the rule causes the "hideListItem" class to be added to the **li**.

**Problem:** The DOM does not get updated immediately, and the list item (now with change tracking markup via the **del** element) continues to display.

In the browser Console, if I examine `CKEDITOR.instances['_editor1_']._.data` (or simply call **getData()** on the instance), I see that the document markup contains the list item with the newly added class. Yet when I browse the DOM using the Element tab in the browser tools, the new class is missing from the list item.

In the Console, I can run `instance.setData(instance.getData())` (where "instance" is a reference to my instance of CKEDITOR), and then the DOM updates. But if I include this in the rule, I get into an infinite loop.

How do I cause CKEditor to write the data model to the DOM?

**Code:**

```js
this.editor.on('instanceReady', () => {
  const hideDeletedListItems = {
    elements: {
      li: element => {
        if(shouldHideElement(element)) {
          element.addClass('hideListItem')
        }
      }
    }
  }

  this.editor.dataProcessor['htmlFilter'].addRules(hideDeletedListItems, {
    priority: 10,
    applyToAll: true
  })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As far, as i know filtering happens when you try set or get content of CKEditor. And you want to apply you script on content editing.

Instaed, how about run your function on `change` event ?

Something like this (Not tested)

```
CKEDITOR.on('change', function (event) {
    $(this.document.$).find("li").each(function () {
        if (shouldHideElement($(this))) {
            $(this).addClass('hideListItem')
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you SAZ for your quick response. Your comment about when filtering  occurs was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Modifying the DOM on 'change' as SAZ proposed is the general approach I ended up with, but with some important modifications.

#### Issues

There are two issues I needed to limit or overcome with the proposed approach:

1. Frequency. I'm using the code to modify not only **li** elements, but also headers, and eventually table rows and lists themselves. Even without running perf tests, that seemed like it could potentially involve a lot of cycles to process everything.
2. Preserving ability to undo. The problem with modifying the DOM in code is that it's my app that makes the modifications, not the user. If the user presses CTRL+Z, the **user's** last action should be undone (not simply the app's last action).

   E.g., If I modified 20 **li** elements in code in response to the user deleting the content of the first **li** element on the page, then CTRL+Z would only undo the class change my app made on **li** number 20, instead of undoing the user's content deletion of **li** number 1.

**Issue resolutions:**

1. I limited the frequency of running the code by listening only for the `lite:change` event (it's really only when I ever need it).
2. I overcame the undo problem by locking the CKEditor snapShot prior to my DOM processing, and then unlocking and updating the snapShot when I was done. That way, CKEditor treats all of the DOM changes that my code makes as a single frame in the undo stack.

#### Solution

> I showed JavaScript in the original question. However, I'm actually using
>   TypeScript, and show that below to help clarify what's being acted on.

**TypeScript:**

```
const trackChangePlugin = this.editor.plugins.lite.findPlugin(this.editor)

const processElementDisplay = (elementTag: string) => {
  const elementCollection: CKEDITOR.dom.nodeList = this.editor.document.getElementsByTag(elementTag)
  // newer versions of CKEditor have a toArray() function, but I'm using an older version, so I created my own:
  const elementArray = this.convertNodeListToArray(elementCollection)
  elementArray.forEach((el:CKEDITOR.dom.element) => {
    if (shouldHideElement(el) && trackChangesPlugin._isVisible) el.$.setAttribute('data-hideElement', 'false')
    else if (shouldHideElement(el)) el.$.setAttribute('data-hideElement', 'true')
    else el.$.removeAttribute('data-hideElement')
  })
}

const fixChangeTrackingDeletions = () => {
  this.editor.fire('lockSnapshot')
  processElementDisplay('li')
  this.editor.fire('unlockSnapshot')
  this.editor.fire('updateSnapshot')
}

this.editor.on('lite:showHide', fixChangeTrackingDeletions)

this.editor.on('lite:change', fixChangeTrackingDeletions)
```

**CSS:**

```
li[data-hideElement='true'] {
  display:none;
}

li[data-hideElement='false'] {
  display: list-item;
}
```